# Clearing attributes in Tritium

Tags: attributes, tritium

What's the best way to clear all attributes of an element with Tritium? Do I have to enumerate all existing attributes with attribute(%name, "") ?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use the remove function by itself after selecting an item.

remove("@*")

You could even select the node first

remove("//node/@*")